# Symfony 3.4 push to heroku : Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Twig_ExtensionSet"

Tags: symfony, heroku, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony3.4 and when I try to push on heroku, the push is OK but I get a 500 Error when I try to load the home page:

## heroku logs:

```
from starting to up
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=vast-river-98800.herokuapp.com request_id=b919fcd8-bfb4-459c-a34c-41b1c96adb90 fwd="197.2.135.255" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=922ms status=500 bytes=243 protocol=http
2018-05-25T06:10:24.172878+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-May-2018 06:10:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Twig_ExtensionSet" from the global namespace.
2018-05-25T06:10:24.172986+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you forget a "use" statement? in /app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:105
2018-05-25T06:10:24.172991+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173173+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/var/cache/prod/ContainerEhxnial/appProdProjectContainer.php(1108): Twig_Environment->__construct(Object(Twig_Loader_Filesystem), Array)
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173312+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/var/cache/prod/ContainerEhxnial/getTwig_Controller_ExceptionService.php(10): ContainerEhxnial\appProdProjectContainer->getTwigService()
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173449+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/var/cache/prod/ContainerEhxnial/appProdProjectContainer.php(851): require('/app/var/cache/...')
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173607+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(304): ContainerEhxnial\appProdProjectContainer->load('getTwig_Control...')
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173803+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ContainerControllerResolver.php(78): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('twig.controller...')
2018-05-25T06:10:24.173903+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/B in /app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php on line 105
2018-05-25T06:10:24.174113+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.79.204.56 - - [25/May/2018:06:10:23 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.139 Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```